# Search ec2 instance by its name from aws command line tool

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have an instance named `dev-server-03`. Now how can I search all `dev-server-*` instances from command line?

I am using aws cli tool.

Comment: This depends on how you've named the instance. Did you set the hostname inside the OS, on the AWS console or both?

Comment: Yeah inside the OS hostname is set to same Name.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the convention of putting the name of the instance in a tag with the key of "Name" (this is what the AWS Console does when you enter a name), then you can use the `--filters` option to list those instances with aws-cli:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=dev-server-*'
```

If you just wanted the instance ids of those instances, you could use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters 'Name=tag:Name,Values=dev-server-*' \
  --output text --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].InstanceId'
```

Note: `--query` may require a recent version of aws-cli but it's worth getting.

Comment: Omg it took me almost half an hour to figure this out... how weird is this : `Name=tag:Name`

Comment: Thanks Eric - I was getting multiple instance IDs on the same line, using your query, but https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/914#issuecomment-56210312 suggested `--query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId]` which works for me

Comment: FWIW, the `jq` tool can be used to get similar results to `aws --query` like this: `aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress'` --note the preceding `.` dot.

Comment: can you make describe-instances filters case insensitive?

Comment: Also worth adding filter `'Name=instance-state-name,Values=running'`, as terminated instances show up in results for a while.

Answer (score 17):

You can further filter with name, instance id and private ip with below,

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=*myinstance*" --output json --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[PrivateIpAddress,InstanceId,Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value]' --region us-east-1
```

Comment: This filtering by Key name was exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: Specifying region was exactly thing without which command refused to work. Now it works, thank you!

Comment: surrounding with `*` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `jq`, you can achieve this with:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances | 
jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | 
select(.Tags[].Value | startswith("dev-server-"))'
```

You can append additional filters to `jq` for more specific results, such as:

```
... startswith("dev-server-")) | .PublicDnsName'
```